# How to repeat a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print

```
snirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirt

snirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirtsnirt
```

by using

```
print('''10*'snirt'
10*'snirt' ''')
```

but this python thing would only print

```
'10*'snirt''

10*'snirt'
```

what should i adjust?

Comment: remove the leading and trailing quotes

Comment: `print(10*"snirt", 10*"snirt", sep='\n')`

Comment: `print(10*"snirt", "\n\n", 10*"snirt")`

Comment: The best thing is to learn python from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/ or any good website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
print("snirt" * 10 + "\n" + "snirt" * 10)
```

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) list of escape sequences - it may prove useful.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
print('snirt'*10)
print('snirt'*10)
```

Comment: This is a great way of doing it; clearly shows intent and is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why the triple "'" ?

just use

```
print(2*(10*'snirt'+'\n'))
```